# Unusual CT tree ID please

Tags: identification, trees, fruit-trees

Please help me ID this tree. I have been trying to find it for a few years now and I don’t know what it is.

The tree looks like a dogwood right until the fruit start to swell, then one realized it isn’t a dogwood.

The fruit looks almost like Lychee, however that isn’t possible because these trees I have only found in Connecticut USA.

I have attached two pictures to help.

[image: bunch of fruit]
[image: truck and branches (and my dog)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right - the tree IS a dogwood, specifically, [Cornus kousa](https://render.fineartamerica.com/images/rendered/default/print/5.375/8.000/break/images-medium-5/kousa-dogwood-cornus-kousa-dr-nick-kurzenko.jpg). There are more details [here](https://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=j910).

Comment: Oh that’s so weird. All the dogwood I had ever seen previous had fruits that looked more like hawthorne or rose hip fruits. Thank you!